# How to force git rebase on top of master?

Tags: git

While rebasing `git rebase master` I notice there are conflicts. I don't care the changes that was made to master, I just want to put my current branch on top of master. How to force rebase so that your current branch is on top of master?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
git rebase -s recursive -X theirs master
```

It will rebase your current branch onto `master` using the default `recursive` strategy.

The `-X theirs` switch applies the `theirs` option to the strategy, which means if it hits a conflict, it will automatically overwrite 'our' changes with 'their' changes. In this rebase, 'our' changes are the ones on `master` (the rebase 'root') and 'their' changes are those which are being rebased onto master (the ones from your current branch).